# pbuilder , is there a way to generate and keep log files with human-readable time-stamps

Tags: debian, pbuilder, cowbuilder

This is what my existing `~/.pbuilderrc` is which is symlinked to `~/root/.pbuilderrc`

```
$ cat ~/.pbuilderrc 
BASEPATH="/var/cache/pbuilder/sid-amd64/base.cow"
DISTRIBUTION="sid"
MIRRORSITE="http://deb.debian.org/debian/"
# Enable build log
 PKGNAME_LOGFILE="yes"
```

while I am understanding how cowbuilder and pbuilder works, is it possible to have a log file which shows how the build happened even after the build is successfully created.

Update - I am using cowbuilder and don't see any way to have detailed logs to keep after a run happens.

Answer (score 2):

If you run `pbuilder` manually, you can use the `--logfile` and `--loglevel` options to specify where and what to log.

Generally speaking though you’ll use `pbuilder` *via* another tool, which will take care of logs for you. For example, `pdebuild` will leave a log file ending in `.build`, with start and end timestamps, containing the build logs, alongside the packages it gets from `pbuilder`.

The same applies to `cowbuilder`: `pdebuild --pbuilder cowbuilder` will build a package using `cowbuilder` and leave a log file names after the package, ending in `.build`, alongside the resulting packages (typically in the parent directory).

Comment: I updated my query and now have cowbuilder in the mix.